# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{n}} \cdot x^{2^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

By Cauchy Hadamard Theorem,

$$R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_{n}|^{1/2^{n}}} $$

But

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}|^{1/2^{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} |\frac{1}{n^{n}}|^{1/2^{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} |1/n|^{n/2^{n}} = L$$

Then

$$\text{log}(L) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n}} |1/n|.$$

Since $1/n > 0$
 always,

$$\log(L) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n}} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2^{n}} = 0. $$

Therefore $L = e^{0} = 1$.

Therefore $R = 1$. Am I right? Pretty sure it's wrong I think it should be $R = \infty$. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What is your exponent of $x$ exactly? $2n$ or $2^n$?

Comment: It is $2^{n}$, not $2n$. Just edited the title. It was a typo.

Comment: That $\log L$ seems not to be right.

Comment: ok. it is a new technique I saw online. I don't know how else to evaluate the limit. I tried to use power rule of logarithm

Comment: what's wrong with log $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "new technique" should be like this.
$$
L = \lim_n \exp \left(\frac n {2^n} \log \left(\frac 1n \right)\right) = \lim_n \exp \left( \frac {-n \log n}{2^n}\right). 
$$
Since
$$
0 \leqslant \frac {n \log n}{2^n} \leqslant \frac {n^2}{\binom n 3} \to 0, 
$$
the limit $L =\exp 0= 1$. And the answer is not correct.

#### UPDATE

For the ratio test,
$$
\ell = \lim_n \left. \frac {x^{2^{n+1}}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\middle/ \frac {x^{2^n}} {n^n} \right. = \lim_n \frac {x^{2^n}}{ \left( \dfrac {n+1}n \right)^n \cdot (n+1)} = \lim_n \frac 1 {\mathrm e} \cdot \frac {x^{2^n}} {n+1}
$$
The limit would be different when $x$ varies. If $|x|>1$, then $\ell = +\infty$, since $x^{2^n} = |x|^{2^n} = (1+a)^{2^n}[a > 0] > 2^n a$, and $$\frac {x^{2^n}}{n+1} > \frac {2^n a}{n+1} > \frac {\binom n 2 a}{n+1} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} +\infty.$$
If $|x|\leqslant 1$, then
$$
0 \leqslant \frac {x^{2^n }}{n+1} \leqslant \frac 1{n+1} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0, 
$$
hence $\ell = 0$.

Conclusion: the series converges iff $x \in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: There are conflicting answers below now..

Comment: what's wrong with my computation though?

Comment: @DillainSmith $$\log \left(\left|\frac 1 {n^n}\right|^{1/2^n}\right) = \frac n {2^n}\color{red}{\log |1/n|}, \neq \frac n{2^n} |1/n|. $$

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the radius of convergence is 1.

Another way to see this is that for any positive $a$, the quantity $(1+a)^{2^n}$ will grow extremely quickly with $n$, even much faster than $n^n$ will. In fact, even the *log* of $(1+a)^{2^n}$ is growing exponentially with $n$, whereas the log of $n^n$ is growing far more slowly--only growing on the order of $n \log n$.

Comment: There are some conflicting answers.

Comment: The OP is correct on the answer, but the computation is not all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint::

for any real number r we will check this series is convergent or not. This is a series of positive real numbers. $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{n}} \cdot r^{2^{n}}$.

Now you can use D'Alembert's ratio test. I think lim $\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=0$ for $[-1 , 1]$.For $|r| >1$ we can use the other Positive real number series tests.

Comment: I cannot successfully show that the ratio equals $0$. Also, this answer is not the same as Mike's